# Fill data into all of my spans

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 8 spans, 4 of the spans with values retrieved from Database are visible when page loads. The other spans are in my own popup box, when a user clicks on the button to view the popup, the value from the spans that were visible needs to also be inside the spans within the popup box.

So I used a each() function with two classes, '.heart' is the class that has the first 4 spans which are visible when page loads. '.likes-count' is another class that has 4 spans within a popup box.

My aim is to assign whatever value is in the first 4 spans to the other spans within popup box.

Im currently stuck in the code below.

## JS

```js
$('.heart, .likes-count').each(function(i, element) {
  var thisID = "#" + $(this).attr('id'); // '#like1', '#like2'
  var getAgain = "." + $(thisID + " span").attr('class'); // .likeCount1

  getAgain = $(getAgain).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `getAgain = $('.' + getAgain).text();`

Comment: Please can you [edit] to show the relevant HTML structure of the page. It is hard to picture when just written as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the spans of your first div using jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). The callback function of `each` gives you an index parameter which you can use to select the corresponding indexed span of the other div.

```js
$("#hearts span").each(function(index){
  var text = $(this).text();
  $("#likes span").eq(index).text( text );
});//each
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hearts">
  <span>12</span>
  <span>24</span>
  <span>36</span>
  <span>48</span>
</div>

<div id="likes">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You are just genius my friend! I couldn't believe how simple it was. Here's the link to explain what I wanted. Click on any project and a pop up will open with my likes: http://fullstackdeveloper.co/index#java-projects

Comment: @OOP Checked your link :) Looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$('.heart').each(function(i) {
  $('.likes-count:eq('+i+')').text($(this).text())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function of `.text()` instead of using `.each()` to achieve this:

```js
var heartspans = $("#hearts span");
$("#likes span").text(function(i,o){
   return heartspans.eq(i).text();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hearts">
  <span>12</span>
  <span>24</span>
  <span>36</span>
  <span>48</span>
</div>

<div id="likes">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a nice implementation :)